# Posting a list of entities using mvc+entity framework causes InvalidOperationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an action that has this signature:

```
public ActionResult Update(ContactForm contactForm)
```

ContactForm is a class from an edmx file. No code first. Its EF 5.0.0.
The edmx file is auto generated.

I have a relation from ContactForm to ContactFormField, which causes a navigation property.
I named it "Fields". It is of type

```
EntityCollection<ContactFormField>
```

When I have fields (and only then) included in the posting caused by post variables that looks like this:

```
ContactForm.Fields[0].Name=foo&ContactForm.Fields[1].Name=bar
```

etc...

I get an InvalidOperationException before the action is even called.

It occurs in the setter of Fields.

The message is:

> The EntityCollection has already been initialized. The
>   InitializeRelatedCollection method should only be called to initialize
>   a new EntityCollection during deserialization of an object graph.

If I try to have an action that takes Fields separately, adding an argument like

```
public ActionResult Update(ContactForm contactForm,
  IEnumerable<ContactFormField> fields)
```

...those will be retrieved correctly, but for each field I have yet another list of ContactFieldAlternative. In other words, I need to be able to post sub objects.

How do I get rid of the exception?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is how the model binder is interpreting your URL string.  The model binder doesn't have any logic which allows it to assume that multiple parameters in the URL string represent the same object.  Therefore, instead of creating one instance of `ContactForm` and binding your fields, it's trying to create an instance of `ContactForm` and bind `Fields[0]` to that, then trying to create another instance of `ContactForm` to bind `Fields[1]` to, which obviously your method signature doesn't accept.  Without creating a custom overload to the model binder, you really can't submit your form values with this URL pattern (and shouldn't anyway, imo).  The intended method for accepting a complex object through a post is either through form elements or JSON.  One of the prime objectives of the ASP.Net MVC framework is the use of restful URLs, which your parameter list in the URL isn't.

Comment: proper form elements are submitted as part of the post process, not as part of the url string... the `ContactForm.Fields[0].Name=foo&ContactForm.Fields[1].Name=bar` line indicates these are coming as individual url string parameters and not as part of the form submission.

Comment: That string is not a part of the url, but the body of the post action. The string is actually caused by form elements.

Comment: hmmm, that sounds like something is wrong with the form then... can you post the code body of the form?

Comment: I have confirmed that post variables look like they should. The form has hidden fields that are added to it manually.